# Geolocation Google Maps API in Extjs 4.2

Tags: google-maps, geolocation, extjs4.2

I am trying to put a google map with my web system that will track the terminals I have with their respective geolocation. I already have my API Key from google. So, I am using these codes

****EDIT***

this is my current code but I can only get a blank page.

```
Ext.ns('dlti.view.widget');
//Order Window View
Ext.define('dlti.view.widget.UserHome' ,{
extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
id: 'dlti-user-home',
alias: 'widget.UserHome',
layout: {
    type: 'hbox',
    region: 'center'
},



        items:[
                {xype: 'gmappanel',
                title: 'Map',
                region: 'center',
        id:  'mygooglemap',
        zoomLevel: 3,
        gmapType: 'map',
        mapConfOpts:['enableScrollWheelZoom','enableDoubleClickZoom','enableDragging'],
    mapControls: ['GSmallMapControl','GMapTypeControl','NonExistantControl'],
        setCenter: {
            'lat': 37.4419,
            'lng': -122.1419
        }
                }


]


});
```

Comment: What is this xtype ? Are you using an extension or is it defined in your code ? Please provide the code for it or a link if it is a third party module.

Comment: I edited my codes now. I am trying to display a map with geolocation on it.

Comment: you have to load google map api script in your web application. Like this in the html file                                             <script id="google" type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>

Comment: @SridharBoganathan it says cannot read property 'Geocoder' of undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add

```
Ext.application({

    requires: [
        'Ext.ux.GMapPanel'
    ]
.....
});
```